# Firebase Deploy Functions Failed (Linux): libc.so.6, GLIBC_2.28, required by node

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a function which *is working* locally with the emulators, but, when trying to deploy, give me this:

```
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function <function-name>(us-central1)...
Build failed: node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28'
not found (required by node); Error ID: 653c7ba4

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        <function-name>(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Downgrade my Node version from 18 to 16.

   Yes, I do have this in my `package.json`:

   ```json
   "engines": {
     "node": "16"
   },
   ```
2. Rebuild everything from scratch with Node 16.

I think `libc.so.6` is related to Java, but I don't know how that helps. Here is my `java --version`:

```
java 19 2022-09-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19+36-2238)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19+36-2238, mixed mode, sharing)
```

> I'm using Archcraft, a distro based on Arch Linux.

> I've just realized that I can share my whole repo, since it's an open source project. [Here it is](https://github.com/psygo/go-brasil-ranking/tree/9c44182e545ed7cd24b3f0ca947f521c65f846ee).

> I ended up [posting this on the respective Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6642), since I think at least a more helpful error message would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my mistake was that my `node` version in `package.json` was actually `18.x.x`, and now that I went back to a `16.x.x`, everything seems to work fine — I was confused because my global `node` is `16.x.x`. That error message really doesn't help though...

Also, I don't know why but deploying defaults to US even though I'm registered as `southamerica-east1`, but that's another issue entirely...